# Zend Studio + Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

Zend Framework has this "Run" button... this works on individual php files. but i am curious how would this work if you are using Zend Framework (or others) where everything (requests, etc) must go through the bootstrap file first before the actual file you are editing is executed?

Comment: AFAIK you'd use run for scripts testing perhaps. for example backup cron scripts, lg managements scripts, email scripts that perhaps decoupled from the rest of the app.   For regular debugging i'd use standard remote xdebug/zend_debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on your public/index.php file
Choose "run as php web page"
It will ask you what URL you want to view while it profiles index.php
You can specify whatever url, but Zend requires that 'index.php' be in the url.
This is okay, though, because the rest of Zend Framework will ignore it.

For example, if you want to profile:
     http://www.mydomain.com/accounts/view

you would simply type in:
     http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/accounts/view

Then you can watch the Zend Studio profiler go to work :)

I figured this out by watching Zend's product screencasts, here:
    http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/videos

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is a way of running a certain file through the bootstrap file,
since for the application to reach that file it would need to go through your routing system and the IDE has no way of knowing what will that URI be.